# how do i use java classes in web context?

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat

I have a text file and a class (Reader) that reads the text file and stores each line in a `String []`.

```
String name;
String [] lines;

Reader(String name){
    this.name = name;
}

public String toString(){
    return this.name;
}

public readFile(String filename){
    String line = "";
    int i = 0;
    try{
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));

        while(line = reader.readLine()) != null){
            lines[i] = line;
            i++;
        }// while
        reader.close();
    }
    catch(etc...){}
}
```

I wish to print each array element in table on my jsp page.

```
Reader r = new Reader("test");
out.print(r.toString());
```

works and prints 'test' but...

```
r.readFile("test.txt")
for (int i=0; i < r.lines.length; i++)
    out.print(r.lines[i])
```

does not... However if I run this on the command line its prints the lines [ ] fine

How do I go about doing it in web context?

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8661780/how-can-i-use-use-java-classes-in-a-web-app

Comment: have you tried debugging?? log what you get out of r.readFile(...)...do you have the file available/accessible to your webserver??

Comment: deleted other question (or voted to anyhow)
@Nadir I am a newbie to jsp stuff... I have my jsp file in root folder and have Reader and test.txt in /WEB-INF/classes/test/
Reader is in test package

Comment: Probably, the problem is that since you have moved it to the web context, the input file is not being found. First try to make sure the file is found.

Comment: Update the post with, the code that opens the file for reading, and the exact location of the input file, package where `Reader` belong.

Comment: It's depends on the code that opens it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing the following:

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));
```

with

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(filename)));
```

That should work since the input file is in the same package as `Reader`.

**Update:**

I think the problem lies in the `TeamData`.

```
readFile("skytest\\data.file")
```

That's not a valid path to the file. Neither in filesystem, nor in the classpath.
Since, the data.file is in the classpath, you can use `getResourceAsStream` to load it.
And, since skytest is the root directory (package), `"/skytest/data.file"` would also be valid here (the leading `/` means relative package root). Or, since the file lies in the same package as the `TeamData`, just the file name should be enough `"data.file"`.

So, use of the following:

```
readFile("data.file")
```

And change the following:

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(requiredFile));
```

to

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(requiredFile)));
```

Also, the following is really a bad practice (that's called swallowing the exception):

```
catch (IOException ioe) {
    //do something about the exception here
    return false;
}
```

Comment: What do you have here: `catch(etc...){}`? I am just trying to see if any exception is being swallowed.

Comment: I have just noticed that compiling the class with no package declared has different behaviour. could that have anything to do with it?

Comment: just `catch(IOException e){System.err.print(e);}`

Comment: And you don't see any exception on console?

Comment: no... this is actually an abstract of my problem... is it possible I can send you my code and maybe you can see?

Comment: what is your email?... otherwise send me a blank and i will respond with .rar vybz1000@msn.com

Comment: Ok I just sent you a blank email.

Comment: Thanks, originally I did just use `"data.file"` but its stopped working when I put the classes in a package... I will attempt the changes. Also in windows \ is used to delimit directories and file the reason for two i.e. \\ is because \ is the escape character in java

Comment: Yes that's what I was trying to say - if it's windows, and you go by filesystem then the valid absolute path should be something like `"C:\\path\\to\\file\\data.file"`. But here you should not go by the filesystem, since your file is in the calsspath, JVM can locate it when using something like `getResourceAsStream`.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    try
    {
        reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("path/to/filename.txt")));
        String nextLine = reader.readLine();
        while (nextLine != null)
        {
            System.out.println(nextLine); // do stuff with the line you read in.
            nextLine = reader.readLine();
        }
        reader.close();
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```